# 'str' object has no attribute 'turtle' in Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to write turtle code with turtle shape and a color and drawing T letter. The following is my code: It gives me run time
 Error with shape! Please help me to correct it! Thanks

```
import turtle # Import the required library

ft = turtle.Turtle
ft.shape("turtle")
ft.color(255)
ft.forward(100)
ft.backward(50)
ft.left(90)
ft.forward(200)
```

Comment: If you are getting an error then you need to post it here exactly as it appears for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors in this code.  Along with the missing parentheses that [@piokuc noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52334748/6243352):

```
ft = turtle.Turtle()
```

This line will also cause an error:

```
ft.color(255)
```

The `color()` function is fairly flexible about its argument:

```
color(colorstring), color((r,g,b)), color(r,g,b)
```

But `ft.color(255)` is invalid for two reasons.  First, it's not a valid argument and second it's assuming a 0 - 255 color scale which is incorrect.  The default color mode for turtle is 0.0 - 1.0 unless you change it with `turtle.colormode(255)`.

Finally, you might want to end with `turtle.done()` at the bottom of your code, unless you're running under a development environment that doesn't require it.

PS: Your 'T' is upside down!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the second line from:

```
ft = turtle.Turtle
```

to

```
ft = turtle.Turtle()
```

After you make the change variable `ft` will point to an instance of the class `Turtle` from the `turtle` module and you will be able to call methods of this object, like `shape`, `color`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do `ft = turtle.Turtle()` , Rather just import turtle, then the function for the shape is `shape(name = "turtle")`.

This is what the program should look like:

```
import turtle
shape(name = "turtle")
color("blue") #The color you want
forward(100)
backward(50)
left(90)
forward(200)
```

Comment: This doesn't work as written. The import would have to be `from turtle import *` in order for `shape`, `color`, etc, to be defined. But wildcard imports are not good practice as it dumps over a hundred functions into the global namespace leading to name collisions and further burgs. Better to stick to OP's approach and create a `Turtle` instance. OP just needs to add `()` to the `Turtle()` call, as described in other answers.